# Change existing Streamlit project "Main function" since Home.py is renamed?

Tags: streamlit

I'm deploying a Streamlit app to Streamlit's platform.  I'm using Streamlit 1.29.0.

From what I understand, when the GitHub repo is connected, `streamlit run Home.py` is called to run the app on the Streamlit server.  But what if my `Home.py` file is changed after creating the app on Streamlit?

I understand you are asked the main function when you first create an app:

[image]

But how do you change once you have created your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the app has to be deleted from Community Cloud and re-deployed if you've changed the name of the main Python file.